# Project Euler question8

Tags: c#, string, char

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong. The result should be ok but it does not mach.

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

```
Console.WriteLine("This prouct calculates the prouct of thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number!");

string numbers = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"+
                 "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"+
                 "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"+
                 "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"+ 
                 "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"+ 
                 "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"+
                 "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"+ 
                 "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"+ 
                 "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"+ 
                 "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"+ 
                 "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"+ 
                 "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"+ 
                 "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"+ 
                 "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"+ 
                 "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"+ 
                 "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"+ 
                 "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"+ 
                 "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"+ 
                 "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"+ 
                 "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

char n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, n12, n13;
int c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13;
        
long tempProd=0;
        
for (int i= 0;i<=numbers.Length-13; i++)
{       
     n1 = numbers[i];
     c1 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n1);
     n2 = numbers[i + 1];
     c2 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n2);
     n3 = numbers[i + 2];
     c3 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n3);
     n4 = numbers[i + 3];
     c4 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n4);
     n5 = numbers[i + 4];
     c5 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n5);
     n6 = numbers[i + 5];
     c6 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n6);
     n7 = numbers[i + 6];
     c7 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n7);
     n8 = numbers[i + 7];
     c8 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n8);
     n9 = numbers[i + 8];
     c9 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n9);
     n10 = numbers[i + 9];
     c10 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n10);
     n11 = numbers[i + 10];
     c11 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n11);
     n12 = numbers[i + 11];
     c12 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n12);
     n13 = numbers[i + 12];
     c13 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n13);

     long prod = c1 * c2 * c3 * c4 * c5 * c6 * c7 * c8 * c9 * c10 * c11 * c12 * c13;

     if (prod > tempProd)
     {
         tempProd = prod;
     }
}
     Console.WriteLine("The result we are looking for is: " + tempProd);
```

Comment: c1, c2, etc are `int`s. c1 * c2 * ... is also an int and it will overflow. Just cast c1 to `long`: `(long)c1 * c2 * ...`

Comment: I see. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using int values with long! change c1,c2 into long ones